# Free Test Automation alternatives to Appium

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium

I am looking for some free alternatives to Appium for test automations.

I'd prefer some **platform-independent** frameworks like Appium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium is the most used cross-platform Mobile Testing Tool for hybrid and native iOS and android (from v2.3 onwards) apps from the market.

If you are looking for options for mobile testing can try other options like [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/), [Robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium), [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso)

Or for web [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/), [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/), [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/), or [Robot Framework](https://robotframework.org/)

Comment: Ok thanks. Are there some alternatives that can be used not for a specific platform? For example Appium can be used for Windows, iOS and Android apps.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, all frameworks will be compatible with one or more platforms. Some only work with a specific platform, while others can be cross-platform.

Comment: Ok thanks! Can you give me some advices for starting tests with Appium? I couldn't find an installation guide that is clear. Each website I consulted says something different from others

Comment: Try their official documentation https://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/?lang=en they explain in a simple way how to start using